# Updating variable using last selector, when the DOM changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a carousel and can't get my head around why the variable keeps pulling the original value of the DOM, despite the DOM changing:

```
// Slide container selector
var carouselSlides = $('#carousel_1 #carousel_slides');

// Selects last slide in the DOM
var cloneSlide = $('#carousel_slides .carousel_slide').last().clone();

// Prepend last slide to slide container
cloneSlide.prependTo(carouselSlides);

function changeSlideNext() {

    carouselSlides.animate({
        left: '-=980'
    }, 1000, 'easeOutExpo', function() {

        // Remove prepended slide
        cloneSlide.remove();

        // Move first slide to the last
        $('#carousel_slides .carousel_slide').first().appendTo(carouselSlides);
        carouselSlides.css('left','-980px');

        // Add new prepended slide when animation is complete (and DOM is updated)
        cloneSlide.add().prependTo(carouselSlides);

    });

}
```

*The above code always prepends the last slide in the original DOM.* How do I select the .last() slide after the DOM has been updated?

Comment: why are you calling `cloneSlide.add()`? This is not related to your question.

Comment: The variable cloneSlide grabs the last slide in the DOM, clones it, then adds it to the slide container.

Comment: Calling `add()` does nothing to change that behavior. It's absolutely unneeded.

Comment: Ah right, removed it and edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function changeSlideNext() {
    carouselSlides.animate({
        left: '-=980'
    }, 1000, 'easeOutExpo', function() {
        var cloneSlide = $('#carousel_slides .carousel_slide:first').clone();

        // Remove first slide
        $('#carousel_slides .carousel_slide:first').remove();

        // Append new slide to last
        cloneSlide.appendTo(carouselSlides);    
    });    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only assign to `cloneSlide` once, outside the function. Calling `changeSlideNext()` doesn't assign any different value to it - there's no reason to expect it to be different.

You'll want to keep selecting the last slide within the function, e.g.:

```
carouselSlides.animate({
    left: '-=980'
}, 1000, 'easeOutExpo', function() {

    // Remove prepended slide
    cloneSlide.remove();

    // Move first slide to the last
    cloneSlide = $('#carousel_slides .carousel_slide').first().appendTo(carouselSlides);
    carouselSlides.css('left','-980px');

    // Add new prepended slide when animation is complete (and DOM is updated)
    cloneSlide.prependTo(carouselSlides);

});
```

I hope I understood the idea of the function correctly. I'm not absolutely sure which value you wanted for `cloneSlide` and when.